# Implicit flow silent login from an existing cookie

Tags: identityserver4, oidc-client-js

I'm securing a web app with identity server 4. My app is split into 2 oidc clients an `ASP.Net Core MVC` client and a `javascript(angularjs)` client which uses the oidc-client javascript library.

When a user first visits the web app we redirect for log in to identity server, which logs in the mvc client. I want to the javascript client is then logged in using the silent login feature from the oidc-library.
Is it possible? 
Is it an acceptable solution?
any points will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "using the silent feature"?

Comment: I means silent login.

Comment: Is the JavaScript/Angular client served from the MVC application/client that the user first accesses?

Comment: Yes, but it needs `access-token` to sent to my APIs.

Comment: @MikeAnderson, Did you figure this out?

Comment: @Lalman  No.  I leaved that project for a while.